# Meaning of within 72 hours before

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What does this exactly mean:

You must fill in this form within 72 hours before you arrive into Germany.

Does that mean I have to fill the from 3 day before entrance? Or, I can fill it out any day I want unless it's within 72 hours, I mean, Can I fill the form out 10 days in advance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is oddly phrased.  So I think a pragmatic understanding is best.

There is some kind of rule.  If the rule is "you can fill in the form during any 72 hour period"... what is the point of a rule.  If you can fill the form in 10 days before, why even have a rule?

So it must mean in the 72 hours before arriving in Germany.  Probably this is a form to confirm that you have passed a covid test or something similar that needs to be done "shortly" before you enter the country.

So what it "exactly means" is unclear (it is unidiomatic, and borderline grammatical)  What it really means is pretty certain.

Comment: thanks, yes it's vague, that's why I asked.